# Form Validation with pattern using js

Tags: forms, validation

> Write a program to take a password as an input from the user. The
> password must qualify these requirements:
> a. It should contain alphabets and numbers
> b. It should not start with a number
> c. It must at least 8 characters long
> d. If the password does not meet the above requirements, prompt
> the user to enter a valid password. For character codes of a-z,
> A-Z & 0-9

I'm using the following code. Don't know why the pattern is always false.

```
 const pattern = /([a - zA - Z][a - zA - Z0 - 9]{ 8, })/;
    
    const userInput = prompt('Enter Password');
    console.log(pattern.test(userInput));
    
    // while (!pattern.test(userInput)) {
    //   prompt("Please Enter valid password")
    // }
    
    alert('Correct password');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**

```js
const pattern = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
const patternTwo = /^[0-9]+$/;

let userInput;

do {
  userInput = prompt("Please Enter valid password");
} while (!pattern.test(userInput) || userInput.length < 8 || patternTwo.test(userInput[0]));

alert('Correct password');
```